# Tkinter Basic Layout with Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling with a really basic layout for a text-based game. Why does the text in the first column stop before the end of the string, and why is the window so tall? Code below, any help appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class TreasureHunt:

    def __init__(self, master):
        app = Frame(master)
        app.grid()

        self.mono_font = tkFont.Font(family="monospace",size=24,weight="bold")
        self.instructions = "Find the hidden treasure!\n\nUse the arrow keys to select where to look, then press Enter to check. \
        There is a 50/50 chance you will be told the distance from the treasure. Keep hunting until you find it. Good luck!"

        self.info = Text(app, wrap=WORD, padx=10, pady=10, bd=0,width=10)
        self.info.insert(1.0,self.instructions)
        self.info.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N)

        self.island = Text(app, bg="cyan",bd=0, padx=20, pady=20, font=self.mono_font,width=20)
        self.island.insert(1.0, "ready")
        self.island.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.display_grid()

    def display_grid(self):
        self.matrix = [["# " for col in range(8)] for row in range(8)]
        for row in range(len(self.matrix)):
            row_str = "".join(self.matrix[row]) +"\n"
            self.island.insert(1.0,row_str)


root = Tk()
game = TreasureHunt(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand this part of the question: "Why does the text in the first column stop before the end of the string". It doesn't appear to "stop" to me -- it wraps to the next line. Is that what you mean?

Comment: With the code as it is, the text stops at  "from the treasure." "Keep hunting until you find it. Good luck!" is missing. I'm guessing the vertical space of the first column is full, even though it appears otherwise due to the vertical height of the right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the window is so tall is because you don't give an explicit height to anything, so Tkinter has to rely on its defaults. By default a text widget will be 24 lines tall.

The widget on the right uses the tallest font, causing it to be the tallest widget in the window. The window will try to fit everything, so if you make that text widget smaller the whole window will be smaller.

```
self.island = Text(app, ..., height=9)
```

I don't quite know what you eman by "the text in the first column [stops] before the end of the string". I don't see it stopping, I see it wrapping just as I would expect and just as you instructed it to.  You set a width of 10 characters, and told it to wrap at word boundaries.

Also, when you use `grid`, as a rule of thumb you must give at least one row and one column a weight. The weight is how Tkinter knows how to allocate any extra space. Notice how if you resize the window, the widgets inside don't grow or shrink. That is because the rows and columns they are in have a default weight of 0 (zero).

To change that, use `row_configure` and `column_configure`. For example, if you want the blue area to expand to take up all extra space, give it's row and column a weight of 1 (one):

```
app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

If you do that you'll find ..... nothing changes. Tkinter will indeed give extra space to row 0 and column 1. However, there is more you must do. You need to use the `sticky` attribute when calling `grid` to request that the widget "sticks" to the edges of the space given to it.

```
self.info.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
...
self.island.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

When you do that you'll see .... nothing changes. That is because `app` is a frame, and that frame is inside of the root window. However, you didn't specify a weight for the row and column that `app` is in, and you also didn't specify a `sticky` value for it.

However, if your root window only has exactly one widget, it's a bit easier to use `pack` rather than grid. The reason I say this is that you don't have to worry about setting the weight of a row and column.

Try changing this line:

```
app.grid()
```

... to this:

```
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that, you'll see that now the widgets fill the window, and if you resize the window it all resizes accordingly.

As an interesting exercise, try adding this line where you set the weight of app. Leave the other lines there, you want to give both columns a weight. Try it, and notice what happens when you manually resize the window.

```
app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Notice that both internal widgets expand. The columns have the same weight, so they expand equally. To get the right to expand twice as much as the left, set its weight to 2.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate this kind of in depth explanation of underlying concepts. I'm curious though - I'd got it into my head that mixing grid and pack was a no no, but here app is packed, yet grid_columnconfig seems to refer to an underlying grid. Is the situation something like "we're packing the app frame onto the root window for simplicity, but if other widgets on that frame use grid, allocate these weights?"

Comment: @Robin: mixing grid and pack must be avoided when using both with widgets that share the same parent. It is no problem -- and even preferable! -- to use both in an application as a whole.